# How do I speed up this file creation process?

Tags: python, pandas, large-files, file-writing, fixed-width

I am trying to create a large flat file with fixed width columns that contains multiple layers, but processing seems to be very slow, most likely because I am iterating over each row. 
For context, this is for transmitting insurance policy information.

The hierarchy goes like this:

```
-Policy row
--Property on policy
---Coverage on property
--Property on policy
---Coverage on property
--Owner on policy
--Owner on policy
--Owner on policy
```

Currently I'm loading the four record types into separate dataframes, and then doing a for loop over each type by pulling them based on the parent record's ID, and then writing them to the file. I'm hoping for some sort of hierarchical dataFrame merge that doesn't force me to scan the file each time I want a record.

```
import re
import pandas as pd
import math


def MakeNumeric(instring):
    output = re.sub('[^0-9]', '', str(instring))
    return str(output)

def Pad(instring, padchar, length, align):
    if instring is None:  # Takes care of NULL values
        instring = ''
    instring = str(instring).upper()
    instring = instring.replace(',', '').replace('\n', '').replace('\r', '')
    instring = instring[:length]
    if align == 'L':
        output = instring + (padchar * (length - len(instring)))
    elif align == 'R':
        output = (padchar * (length - len(instring))) + instring
    else:
        output = instring
    return output

def FileCreation():
    POLR = pd.read_parquet(r'POLR.parquet')
    PRP1 = pd.read_parquet(r'PRP1.parquet')
    PROP = pd.read_parquet(r'PROP.parquet')
    SUBJ = pd.read_parquet(r'SUBJ.parquet')
    rownum = 1
    totalrownum = 1
    POLRCt = 0
    size = 900000
    POLR = [POLR.loc[i:i + size - 1, :] for i in range(0, len(POLR), size)]
    FileCt = 0
    print('Predicted File Count: ' + str(math.ceil(len(POLR[0])/ size)) )
    for df in POLR:
        FileCt += 1
        filename = r'OutputFile.' + Pad(FileCt, '0', 2, 'R')
        with open(filename, 'a+') as outfile:
            for i, row in df.iterrows():
                row[0] = Pad(rownum, '0', 9, 'R')
                row[1] = Pad(row[1], ' ', 4, 'L')
                row[2] = Pad(row[2], '0', 5, 'R')
                # I do this for all 50 columns
                outfile.write((','.join(row[:51])).replace(',', '') + '\n')
                rownum += 1
                totalrownum += 1
                for i2, row2 in PROP[PROP.ID == row[51]].iterrows():
                    row2[0] = Pad(rownum, '0', 9, 'R')
                    row2[1] = Pad(row2[1], ' ', 4, 'L')
                    row2[2] = Pad(row2[2], '0', 5, 'R')
                    # I do this for all 105 columns
                    outfile.write((','.join(row2[:106])).replace(',', '') + '\n')
                    rownum += 1
                    totalrownum += 1
                    for i3, row3 in PRP1[(PRP1['id'] == row2['ID']) & (PRP1['VNum'] == row2['vnum'])].iterrows():
                        row3[0] = Pad(rownum, '0', 9, 'R')
                        row3[1] = Pad(row3[1], ' ', 4, 'L')
                        row3[2] = Pad(row3[2], '0', 5, 'R')
                        # I do this for all 72 columns
                        outfile.write((','.join(row3[:73])).replace(',', '') + '\n')
                        rownum += 1
                        totalrownum += 1
                for i2, row2 in SUBJ[SUBJ['id'] == row['id']].iterrows():
                    row2[0] = Pad(rownum, '0', 9, 'R')
                    row2[1] = Pad(row2[1], ' ', 4, 'L')
                    row2[2] = Pad(row2[2], '0', 5, 'R')
                    # I do this for all 24 columns
                    outfile.write((','.join(row2[:25])).replace(',', '') + '\n')
                    rownum += 1
                    totalrownum += 1
                POLRCt += 1
                print('File {} of {} '.format(str(FileCt),str(len(POLR)) ) + str((POLRCt - 1) / len(df.index) * 100) + '% Finished\r')
            rownum += 1
        rownum = 1
        POLRCt = 1
```

I'm essentially looking for a script that doesn't take multiple days to create a 27M record file.

Comment: You would do much better using an actual data base tool for your data base application.  Try SQL, or whatever dialect thereof fits your system best.  Here, you're trying to merge 4 data sets with a hand-coded routine.  Let the existing tools do the hard work for you.

Comment: @Prune How would an SQL db be a more efficient "middle man" in creating a txt file than pandas?

Comment: Is your code correctly indented? Because it looks like your `for` loops are "nested too much". Because right now, your first `for i, row in df.iterrows():` step runs over all rows in `PROP[PROP.ID == row[51]]` which then in their first step run over all the `PRP1…` rows — maybe I'm missing something obvious, but this seems exhaustive. Ideally, you would construct a "clean" temporary DataFrame for each file an then dump it to file.

Comment: @Asmus databases are great at munging data, they're easy to work with, they have built-in query optimizers, you can implement your solution in stages and examine the intermediate states, it uses disk efficiently etc., etc. It sounds like the current solution is thrashing virtual memory.

Comment: @thebjorn I sure know the general advantages of databases :-) But in this *specific* case, the question goes like `file in > munching data in pandas (in memory, fast) > file out`, and using a database would make this at least `file in > store millions of records in sql file > read from sql into memory (perhaps more efficient than in pandas) > file out`. Unless I'm missing something obvious, this sounds way more expensive to me.

Comment: I don't understansd why you write (','.join(row[:51])).replace(',', ''), doesn't it would be more efficent to write (''.join(row[:51])) ?

Comment: Your Pad function could be done directely with format : '{:{fill}{align}.{width}}'.format(row[], fill = padding_char, align=alignement, width=maximum_length)  see https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string-formatting

Comment: @Nico238 The format function is slower than my pad function, and the reason I join with a comma and then remove it, is because otherwise I would lose my white space padding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up populating temp tables for each record level, and creating keys, then inserting them into a permanent staging table and assigning an clustered index to the keys.
I then queried the results while using `OFFSET` and `FETCH NEXT %d ROWS ONLY` to reduce memory size. I then used the multiprocessing library to break the workload out for each thread on the CPU.
Ultimately, the combination of these have reduced the runtime to about 20% of what it was when this question was originally posted.